# Set focus onto a specific window using VBScript

Tags: windows-7, batch, cmd.exe, vbscript

Is there a way to set the focus onto a specific window using VBScript ?

Window name should be settable by something.
(Not an additional program such as AutoIT or so)

(Windows 7 Pro)

Comment: Yes it is possible, but please note, we're not a "please write me a script" kind of site. Can you share us your research, and we'll help you point out where things aren't working as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385843/vbscript-switching-focus-to-window-using-appactivate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AppActivate method](http://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html) available in VBScript can do this

Example to focus on Notepad is below:

```
Dim ObjShell :Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ObjShell.AppActivate("Notepad")
```

You can also wrap this around an HTA application to set program on the fly.