# Use VBS To focus on a specific process without process title or PID

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a VBScript that should work to focus a given process (taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1085899/892036)):

```
Dim ObjShell :Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ObjShell.AppActivate("Notepad")
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work when using the title of a specific process: "Ableton Live 10 Intro.exe" is what I believe to be the title.

[image: Task Manager screenshot]

Here you can see in the task manager that the parent process name is "Ableton Live 10 Intro.exe" (copypasted from the Properties panel). I also noticed that the description is "Ableton Live 10 Intro.exe":

[image]

Apparently [AppActivate()](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/2b9476ce-54a7-4a00-b761-25bf9f36e83f.asp) requires a PID or title string "as it appears in the title bar", but the window title which appears in the title bar is empty. I also don't think I can use the PID to target this process because I don't know what the PID is, as this script should happen when this process launches on login (thus the PID will be different every time).

So how can I target this process given that I have its

- description,
- path of the executable,

but not its

- title,
- PID

Is this even possible? I am new to VBScript. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you trying to activate notepad instead of this exe?

Comment: That was just an example, to show that the script works with other executables given a valid title.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/codeartery/0ea3a74e92d39ce520cffb05a8b99446) probably does what you want but it goes about it in a rather hacky way (by shelling out to PowerShell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
rather than VBScript.

The following AutoHotkey script will activate your `.exe`:

```
WinGet, CalcIDs, List, ahk_exe Ableton Live 10 Intro.exe
If (CalcIDs = 1) ; Calc is NOT minimized
    CalcID := CalcIDs1
else
    CalcID := CalcIDs2 ; Calc is Minimized use 2nd ID
winRestore, ahk_id %CalcID%
winActivate, ahk_id %CalcID%
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
to test. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I have a batch script launching Ableton, and so it also runs this AHK script with `start cmd /c "C:/...focusAbleton.ahk"`. Since Ableton had just been launched in my case, it would never be minimized, and I found that I could only "focus" on a certain pop-up dialog (the window without a name that can be seen in the task manager screenshot above) by removing the `winRestore` line.